# How to fix adding Watermark on Pdf is removing the original content - Python - PyPDF

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf, watermark

I'm trying to add a watermark on to Pdf using the PyPDF library. But the problem is that the output file is basically a watermark and nothing else.
[image: output]

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

template = PdfFileReader(open('sample.pdf', 'rb'),strict=False)
watermark = PdfFileReader(open('watermark logo.pdf', 'rb'),strict=False)
output = PdfFileWriter()

for i in range(template.getNumPages()):
    page = template.getPage(i)
    page.mergePage(watermark.getPage(0))
    output.addPage(page)

file = open('sample1.pdf', 'wb')
output.write(file)
```

The output pdf file doesn't show content but just a watermark. Please help me fix this if anyone knows a solution.

Comment: Probably your watermark image is not transparent and thus covers stuff underneath. You must convert it to an image with transparency channel. Or, alternatively, use the image as a background. Don't know if that works with this package - it does with PyMuPDF.